# using content deployment to move publishing site to product server

Tags: content-deployment

I create a publishing site in sharepoint 2013 in test environment and now I want to move all my site to new environment(product farm) I know I should use content deployment but I do not know how?

Comment: maybe it is better to use backup/restore scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their are couple of ways to move site collection to other farm.

1. Use the [backup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx) and restore method of site collection. Make sure both farm at the same version level.
2. You can use dtabase backup method using sql server.
3. You can use content deployment method but is usually use when you have an authoring farm n publishing farm...this is on going process. If one time activity then this approach is not good.